# Creating a folder shortcut on Desktop using command line

Tags: directory

I know I can create a folder's shortcut by pressing Ctrl and shift, but I wonder how to do it in a command line.

Comment: "pressing Ctrl and Shift" doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: There is a difference between a "shortcut" (quick link to a folder, but does otherwise not change the behaviour of the folder) and a "symlink" (replaces the folder, i.e., makes the folder appear as if moved (actually copied) onto a new location. Please adapt your title if you mean a "link" (like you create with Ctrl Shift Drag), but then this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolik link file in the `Desktop` folder with a `ln` command like this:

```sh
ln -s ~/home/user/some/folder ~/Desktop/some_folder
```

Comment: yeah, but it tells me that the link is broken